# My BuildRowsetFromString works... unless there is a blank value in the row

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm using a `BuildRowsetFromString` function and while it shows the correct data when there are values, or if a record is not in the dataset, if a record appears with blank data I can't get anything to display.

Here's what I've tried:

```
%%[

SET @rowset = LookupOrderedRows("Recently-Browsed",1,"Add Date Desc","EmailAddress", EmailAddr)

IF RowCount(@rowset) == 0 THEN
        SET @browsing = "Not Found"

ELSE RowCount(@rowset) > 0 THEN
        SET @browsing = FIELD(ROW(@rowset, 1), "Product Categories Viewed - Top")
ENDIF
]%%

%%[
SET @CategoryRows = BuildRowsetFromString(@browsing,"|")
  FOR @i = 1 TO RowCount(@CategoryRows) DO

SET @CategoryRow = Row(@CategoryRows,@i)
SET @Category = Field(@CategoryRow,1)
]%%


%%[NEXT @i]%%
```

and then:

```
%%[

IF @category == "" THEN
     SET @browsing = "Null Row"
ELSE SET @browsing = @category

ENDIF]%%

%%=v(@browsing)=%%
```

if `@category` is `null`, it still shows a blank, and not "Null Row" as expected.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should consider the EMPTY() function, which checks for both NULL and empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Ampscript expert, but I think the `IsNull` function might help you out here...

```
%%[

IF @category == "" OR IsNUll(@category) THEN
     SET @browsing = "Null Row"
ELSE SET @browsing = @category

ENDIF]%%
```